# Can't force gems to a specific version in Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

After a bundle update, I want to rollback some gem versions to a specific one. I've tried several options, but I can't do it.

Say I want to use **arel** in its 2.0.9 version. I did the following:

```
sudo gem uninstall arel -v 2.0.10
```

Then in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'arel', '~> 2.0.9'
```

And then:

```
bundle update
```

Then I get:

```
Installing arel (2.0.10)
```

I also tried with **gem cleanup** and deleting **Gemfile.lock**, but no.. I allways get the same arel 2.0.10 installed. Am I missing something? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're telling it to install any patch version greater than or equal to 2.0.9. If you want to specifically install that version just do this:

```
gem 'arel', '2.0.9'
```